# Why does $A \times U_{2}$ and $U_{1}\times B\in \mathcal{B}(\Omega)\Rightarrow A\times B\in \mathcal{B}(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega_{1}, \tau_{1})$ and $(\Omega_{2}, \tau_{2})$ be topological spaces and $\tau:=\tau_{1}\otimes \tau_{2}$ while $\Omega:=\Omega_{1}\otimes \Omega_{1}$

I am attempting to brush up on my topology, I want to show that:

$\mathcal{B}(\Omega_{1})\times \mathcal{B}(\Omega_{2})\subseteq \mathcal{B}( \Omega)$

where $\mathcal{B}(\Omega_{i})$ is the Borel$-\sigma-$algebra of $\Omega_{i}$

Part of the solution used here makes use of the implication:

$A \times U_{2}$ and $U_{1}\times B\in \mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ for any open $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$ $\Rightarrow A\times B\in \mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ (*)

It was intially shown that $\mathcal{A}_{U_{2}}:=\{A\in \mathcal{B}(\Omega_{1}): A \times U_{2}\in \mathcal{B}(\Omega)\}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra for any open $U_{2}$ and correspondingly $\mathcal{B}_{U_{1}}:=\{B\in \mathcal{B}(\Omega_{1}): U_{1}\times B\in \mathcal{B}(\Omega)\}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra for any open $U_{1}$
but I do not see how this would help me show (*) and subsequently that

$\mathcal{B}(\Omega_{1})\times \mathcal{B}(\Omega_{2})\subseteq \mathcal{B}( \Omega)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A \times B=(A\times \Omega_2) \cap (\Omega_1 \times B)$. Take $U_2=\Omega_2$ and $U_1=\Omega_1$.

Comment: Why is it necessary to show that $\mathcal{A}_{U_{2}}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{U_{1}}$ are $\sigma-$algebras? I do not see how it helps in the proof